I got this error Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::assignRole()
I have a small app & I'm using Laravel 11 and I try to expose only the UILD and not IDs
and I got "Call to undefined method App\Models\User::assignRole()"
User.php
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles; // Ensure this is imported
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'ulid',
        'store_id',
        'is_active',
        'wpuserId',
        'phone',
        'avatar_url',
        'description',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
        'ulid',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'email_verified_at',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
    ];

    /**
     * Boot the model.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($user) {
            if (empty($user->ulid)) {
                $user->ulid = Str::ulid()->toBase32(); // Automatically generate a ULID
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Relationship with UserProvider.
     */
    public function userProviders(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserProvider::class);
    }

    /**
     * Relationship with Store.
     */
    public function store(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }

    /**
     * Assign roles to the user and update `model_has_roles` with ULID.
     */
    public function assignRole(...$roles): static
    {
        \Log::info('User.php > Inside assignRole method', ['roles' => $roles, 'user_id' => $this->id]);
        // Log the roles being assigned
        \Log::info('User.php > Assigning roles to user', [
            'user_ulid' => $this->ulid,
            'user_id' => $this->id,
            'roles' => $roles,
        ]);

        try {
            // Call the Spatie method to assign roles
            \Log::info('User.php > Inside try roles', $roles);
            parent::assignRole(...$roles);

            // Log after the parent method call
            \Log::info('User.php > Parent assignRole method executed', [
                'user_id' => $this->id,
            ]);

            // Update the ULID in the model_has_roles table for each role
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                \Log::info('User.php > Processing role', [
                    'role_name' => $role,
                ]);

                $roleModel = Role::where('name', $role)->first();

                if ($roleModel) {
                    \Log::info('User.php > Role found', [
                        'role_id' => $roleModel->id,
                    ]);

                    $updatedRows = DB::table('model_has_roles')
                        ->where('role_id', $roleModel->id)
                        ->where('model_id', $this->id)
                        ->update([
                            'model_ulid' => $this->ulid,
                            'updated_at' => now(),
                        ]);

                    \Log::info('User.php > model_has_roles table updated', [
                        'role_id' => $roleModel->id,
                        'model_id' => $this->id,
                        'updated_rows' => $updatedRows,
                    ]);
                } else {
                    \Log::warning('User.php > Role not found', [
                        'role_name' => $role,
                    ]);
                }
            }

            return $this;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the exception if something goes wrong
            \Log::error('User.php > Error assigning roles', [
                'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'user_id' => $this->id,
            ]);

            throw $e; // Optionally re-throw the exception
        }
    }


    /**
     * Relationship with roles.
     */
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'model_has_roles', 'model_id', 'role_id')
            ->wherePivot('model_type', self::class)
            ->withPivot('model_ulid'); // Include ULID in the relationship
    }

    /**
     * Activate the user.
     */
    public function activate(): void
    {
        $this->is_active = true;
        $this->save();
    }

    /**
     * Deactivate the user.
     */
    public function deactivate(): void
    {
        $this->is_active = false;
        $this->save();
    }
}

Role.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Role extends SpatieRole
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'guard_name',
        'ulid', // Add ULID to fillable fields
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Automatically generate ULID for roles on creation.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($role) {
            if (empty($role->ulid)) {
                $role->ulid = Str::ulid()->toBase32(); // Generate ULID automatically
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Assign this role to a user.
     */
    public function assignToUser(User $user): void
    {
        DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
            'role_id' => $this->id,
            'model_id' => $user->id,
            'model_type' => User::class,
            'model_ulid' => $user->ulid, // Add user ULID during insertion
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'model_has_roles', 'role_id', 'model_id')
            ->withPivot('model_ulid', 'model_type'); // Include ULID and model type in pivot
    }
}

Permission.php
    <?php
    
    
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission as SpatiePermission;
    use App\Models\Permission as CustomPermission;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
    use App\Models\Role;
    
    class Permission extends SpatiePermission
    {
        // Adding HasFactory trait for the Permission model
        use HasFactory;
    
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array<int, string>
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'guard_name',
        ];
    
        /**
         * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
         *
         * @var array<string, string>
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'created_at' => 'datetime',
            'updated_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
        /**
         * The roles that belong to the permission.
         */
        public function roles(): BelongsToMany
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
        }
    }

Permission.php

<?php

return [

    'models' => [

        'permission' => App\Models\Permission::class,
        'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,
    ],

    'table_names' => [

        'roles' => 'roles',
        'permissions' => 'permissions',
        'model_has_permissions' => 'model_has_permissions',
        'model_has_roles' => 'model_has_roles',
        'role_has_permissions' => 'role_has_permissions',
    ],

    'column_names' => [
        'role_pivot_key' => null, //default 'role_id',
        'permission_pivot_key' => null, //default 'permission_id',
        'model_morph_key' => 'model_id',
        'team_foreign_key' => 'team_id',
    ],
    'register_permission_check_method' => true,
    'register_octane_reset_listener' => false,
    'teams' => false,
    'use_passport_client_credentials' => false,
    'display_permission_in_exception' => false,
    'display_role_in_exception' => false,
    'enable_wildcard_permission' => false,

    'cache' => [

        'expiration_time' => \DateInterval::createFromDateString('24 hours'),
        'key' => 'spatie.permission.cache',
        'store' => 'default',
    ],
];

AuthController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Store; // Import the Store model
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Register a new user.
     * When registering a new user, if the role is Admin or User, you might need to assign them to a store.
     * You could add a store_id to the request, and assign that store_id to the new use
     */
    public function register(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        \Log::info('AuthController > Start of register method');

        // Validate request data with required fields
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            'role' => ['required', 'in:SuperAdmin,Admin,User'],
            'store_code' => ['nullable', 'exists:stores,store_code'],
            'phone' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:15'],
            'avatar_url' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
            'wpuserId' => ['nullable', 'string'],
        ]);

        \Log::info('AuthController > Request data validated', ['validatedData' => $validatedData]);

        // Determine the role of the user
        $roleName = $validatedData['role'];

        // Check if the role exists
        $roleExists = Role::where('name', $roleName)->exists();
        \Log::info('AuthController > Role existence check', ['role' => $roleName, 'exists' => $roleExists]);

        if (!$roleExists) {
            \Log::error('AuthController > Role does not exist', ['role' => $roleName]);
            return response()->json(['error' => 'The specified role does not exist.'], 422);
        }

        // Validate store_code based on role
        if (in_array($roleName, ['Admin', 'User']) && empty($validatedData['store_code'])) {
            \Log::error('AuthController > Store code is missing for role', ['role' => $roleName]);
            return response()->json(['error' => 'store_code is required for Admin and User roles.'], 422);
        }

        // Get store_id based on store_code if provided
        $store_id = null;
        if (!empty($validatedData['store_code'])) {
            $store = Store::where('store_code', $validatedData['store_code'])->first();
            if (!$store) {
                \Log::error('AuthController > Invalid store code provided', ['store_code' => $validatedData['store_code']]);
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid store code provided.'], 422);
            }
            $store_id = $store->id;
            \Log::info('AuthController > Store resolved', ['store_code' => $validatedData['store_code'], 'store_id' => $store_id]);
        }

        // Wrap user creation and role assignment in a database transaction
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            \Log::info('AuthController > Beginning user registration transaction');

            // Create the user
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $validatedData['name'],
                'email' => $validatedData['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
                'store_id' => $store_id,
                'phone' => $validatedData['phone'] ?? null,
                'avatar_url' => $validatedData['avatar_url'] ?? null,
                'description' => $validatedData['description'] ?? null,
                'wpuserId' => $validatedData['wpuserId'] ?? null,
            ]);

            \Log::info('AuthController > User created successfully', ['user_id' => $user->id]);

            // Log the traits used by the User model
            \Log::info('AuthController > User traits', ['traits' => class_uses($user)]);

            // Assign the role to the user
            $user->assignRole($roleName);
            \Log::info('AuthController > Role assigned to user', ['user_id' => $user->id, 'role' => $roleName]);

            // Commit the transaction
            DB::commit();
            \Log::info('AuthController > Transaction committed successfully');

            // Fire the Registered event
            event(new Registered($user));
            \Log::info('AuthController > Registered event fired', ['user_id' => $user->id]);

            return response()->json(['message' => 'User registered successfully'], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Rollback the transaction on failure
            DB::rollBack();
            \Log::error('AuthController > Failed to register user', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);

            // Return an error response
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'AuthController > Failed to register user: ' . $e->getMessage(),
            ], 500);
        }
    }

the Log file:
[2024-11-18 01:43:06] local.INFO: AuthController > Start of register method   [2024-11-18 01:43:06] local.INFO: AuthController > Request data validated {"validatedData":{"name":"John Doe","email":"abcd@gmail.com","password":"password123","role":"Admin","store_code":"3456789","phone":"+1234567890","avatar_url":"https://example.com/avatar.jpg","description":"This is a description.","serId":"wp_12345"}}  [2024-11-18 01:43:06] local.INFO: AuthController > Role existence check {"role":"Admin","exists":true}  [2024-11-18 01:43:06] local.INFO: AuthController > Store resolved {"store_code":"3456789","store_id":1}  [2024-11-18 01:43:06] local.INFO: AuthController > Beginning user registration transaction   [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.INFO: AuthController > User created successfully {"user_id":13}  [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.INFO: AuthController > User traits {"traits":{"Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens":"Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens","Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory":"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory","Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable":"Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable","Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles":"Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles"}} [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.INFO: User.php > Inside assignRole method {"roles":["Admin"],"user_id":13}  [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.INFO: User.php > Assigning roles to user {"user_ulid":"01JCYF054BBP8EQCT4ZN2J","user_id":13,"roles":["Admin"]}  [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.INFO: User.php > Inside try roles ["Admin"]  [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.ERROR: User.php > Error assigning roles {"error_message":"Call to undefined method App\Models\User::assignRole()","user_id":13}  [2024-11-18 01:43:07] local.ERROR: AuthController > Failed to register user {"error":"Call to undefined method App\Models\User::assignRole()"}

Just a quick note that you should never be outputting your users' passwords in plaintext anywhere. Make sure those are redacted or removed entirely from your logs.

First, modify the User model to properly implement Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUlids
Now in your user model
public function uniqueIds(): array
{
    return ['ulid'];
}

make sure in your migration $table->ulid('id');
then
php artisan optimize:clear


Ive added and same
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles, HasUlids;
public function uniqueIds(): array
{
    return ['ulid'];
}


and also  in the migration file     public function up(): void
{
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->ulid('ulid')->unique();
